# How can you autogenerate filenames for autosaved VIM sessions?

Tags: session, vim

I know adding the following to `~/.vimrc` will autosave a session file in the current directory with the name 'Session.vim'.

```
autocmd BufWritePre :mksession!
```

However, these files would litter up directories. I would rather save the session file to `/tmp/[some filename which specifies the directory]`.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this expression to generate the file name:

`"/tmp/vimSessions/".substitute(expand("%:p:h"),"/","_","g")`

Ofcourse, you can change the first string to contain whatever directory you want.

**UPDATE:**

Add this to your `vimrc` file:

```
function GetSessionName(useFileName)
    if a:useFileName
        let l:dir=expand("%:p:h")
    else
        let l:dir=getcwd()
    endif
    return fnameescape("/tmp/vimSessions/".substitute(l:dir,"/","_","g"))
endfunction
if !isdirectory("/tmp/vimSessions")
    call mkdir("/tmp/vimSessions")
endif
autocmd VimEnter * if filereadable(GetSessionName(0))|exe "source ".GetSessionName(0)|endif
autocmd BufWritePost * exe "mksession! ".GetSessionName(1)
```

Comment: Thanks - this works well, although I now realize I would like this to auto-load when I open vim as well.

Comment: @Adarsh I updated the answer to include both saving and restoring the sessions.

Comment: I would suggest to add `fnameescape()` around `GetSessionName(1)` everywhere where you write `exe <...>.GetSessionName(1)`.

Comment: Good idea, @ZyX. I figured that since `:mksession` and `:source` take one argument you don't need to escape it, but I just tested it and I was wrong. Anyways, instead of wrapping the function twice, I just added it to the function.  

Also, I changed the first autocmd to use `GetSessionName(0)` so you would get the correct folder even if you open vim in folder view mode.(that's why I put the argument there in the first place, I just forgot to use it the first time...)